# App Store update and softwareupdate in terminal hang indefinitely

Tags: software-update, performance

OSX 10.13.1

The App Store shows a badge of "3" on the icon, but opening it and pressing "Updates" will result in an indefinite hang with low CPU utilization.

Tried going into the terminal and running "softwareupdate -l --verbose". I get "Finding available software" and that's it. It never returns more or accepts input again. Both using my admin account and then doing "sudo su" and running the command with sudo get the same results.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Open Console.app and select `All Messages` under `SYSTEM LOG QUERIES` in the Sidebar. Enter `deny mach-lookup com.apple.securityd.xpc` in the search field at the upper right. Let me know what (if anything) shows up.

Comment: Closest matches. These pop up right when I hit the updates button in app store:  
'kernel Sandbox: App Store(27497) deny(1) nvram-get BSD Name
kernel Sandbox: suggestd(336) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.locationd.desktop.synchronous
kernel Sandbox: MTLCompilerServi(27504) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Users/gavinc
kernel Sandbox: MTLCompilerServi(27504) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
kernel Sandbox: App Store(27497) deny(1) iokit-open AppleUSBMultitouchUserClient
kernel Sandbox: App Store(27497) deny(1) nvram-get glk_free_policy_override'

Comment: [Sorry for the delay in getting back to you; no Internet access all day.] Click on the disclosure triangles at the left end of each of the entries you listed. In the resulting expanded texts, look for any buttons which say "Open Full Report" (or something similar). Click any such buttons wherever you may find one. In each of the reports which appears as a consequence, search for these words: `credentials` `instrument` `auth_entity`. The context in which the words appear doesn't matter--just which ones show up at all. Let me know.

Comment: I'll save some time, possibly: if none of those words show up, then my ability to offer suggestions is at an end. If `credentials` appears, then there is an issue with your Apple ID (possibly your Apple Developer ID, if you have one). The appearance of either of the other two words would require further questions on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help on this! I finally figured it out, well sort of. I found in the logs a recurring softwareupdate error where a `mkdir` command was failing. Ended up searching around on that and fixed it with:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/folders/zz/zy*
```

Appreciate the tip on the Console app. I didn't know about that and it led me to the answer!

Comment: I ran into "operation not permitted" on this because they're protected by csrutil stuff. You could disable that, but I didn't have to, I just booted into recovery mode (hold command+r while booting) and was able to run this command from Utilities > Terminal and it worked.

Comment: This actually helped when simulateously running `sudo softwareupdate -i -a` in Terminal. I could resume my hung up update process